# how to set the size of a tuple's entry?

Tags: python, list, tuples

What do I do if I want to set the size of a particular tuple's entry?

`Foo = namedtuple('Foo', ['row', 'column'])`

like let's say i have a list of tuples inside a different class Bar

```py
  self.listOfFoo = [Foo]
```

I can definitely modify how many Foos there are inside the `listOfFoo`, but can I actually modify how many `row` values there will be?

Comment: It's a tuple - instances of Foo will always only have 1 `row` value.

Comment: it really isn't clear to me what you are asking here

Comment: BTW, `self.listOfFoo = [Foo]` **does not create a list of instances of `Foo**. it creates a list with the `Foo` class in it